Why is texture baking not working well?
I use Blender 4.1 on Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm). I'm trying to bake several textures into one, but this time there are lots of tiny rectangles on my bake result. What's wrong?
Also, there is a notice: Circular dependency for image "Building base color" from object "Building".


Share the file: https://blend-exchange.com/

I just needed to add 1m to extrusion.

